# Windows store app asset doesn't load on tablet

Tags: c#, file-io, windows-store-apps

I am writing a Windows store application that loads `.png` image from assets.

The code:

```
private static readonly string filePath = "ms-appx:///Base/Assets/Faces/img1.png";
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(filePath, UriKind.Absolute));
```

When I test application on computer, image loads correctly, but when I test it on a tablet, image doesn't load. For more information: image doesn't load on ARM processors, on x86 everything works.

Image property set to `Copy always` and `Content`.

Comment: Did you tried that in the simulator?

Comment: it tried it on a tablet surface rt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling the method without `UriKind` parameter:

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(filePath));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but no changes.